# Who's this person with vines on him?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's a person on minecraft creative mode, he has vines on him and red eyes. when you attack him he doesnt atack back, and he moves really slowly. does anyone know what he is called?

Comment: A screenshot would make it easier to identify, also, are you sure you're not on a multiplayer server?

Comment: @RonanForman this is a herobrine spam pun I think.

Comment: Assuming this is not spam, it could possibly be a texture-pack that someone installed.

Answer (score 9):

This answer assumes you're referring to this:

[image: An Iron golem]

It's an [Iron golem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_golem), they spawn around villages and will kill zombies and skeletons that try to attack the villagers. They will also pick up flowers and give them to villagers.

The reason it isn't attacking back is because you're in creative mode, and because it can't harm you it soon gives up on attacking. Either that or you created it yourself (out of iron blocks and a pumpkin) in which case it will not attack you even on survival mode.